# How do I define values in options_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select, erb

I have this options_for_select call:

```
    <%= f.select(:agents, options_for_select(@agents), {},{multiple: true, size: 10, :id => "agents"}) %>
```

There are only currently 2 agents in the database but they are showing up as `#<Agent:0x007fc1b121c490>` format. I want them to display as `@agent.name` and for the value to be `@agent.id`.

How do I edit this code above to get this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a helper specifically for collections, `options_from_collection_for_select` which is to handle exactly this case.

```
<%= f.select(:agents, options_from_collection_for_select(@agents, 'id', 'name'), {},{multiple: true, size: 10, :id => "agents"}) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should directly provide what you want to use as options values and ids:

`<%= f.select(:agents, options_for_select(@agents.map{ |agent| [agent.name, agent.id]}), {},{multiple: true, size: 10, :id => "agents"}) %>`


Refer the [documentation API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Also, probably you would like to select current value:

`<%= f.select(:agents, options_for_select(@agents.map{ |agent| [agent.name, agent.id]}, @current_agent), {},{multiple: true, size: 10, :id => "agents"}) %>`